# Uncaught ReferenceError: web3 is not defined

Tags: solidity, web3js, infura

I am including `web3.js` `0.19.0` and getting the following error from the browser console: `Uncaught ReferenceError: web3 is not defined at file.html:270` when using it with the following code:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/web3@0.19.0/dist/web3.js"></script>

<script>

window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
        console.log('Web3 Detected! ' + web3.currentProvider.constructor.name)
        web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
    } else {
        console.log('No Web3 Detected... using HTTP Provider')
        web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://ropsten.infura.io/key"));
        if(!web3.isConnected())
            console.log("not connected");
        else
            console.log("connected"); 
    }
});

web3.eth.defaultAccount = "0x..."; // <-- here starts the error "web3 undefined!!"
var myContract = web3.eth.contract(...abi...);
var myInstance = myContract.at('0x...');

</script>
```

On the other hand the browser gives me a positive message and tells me:

```
No Web3 Detected... using HTTP Provider    (because I don't use Metamask)

connected
```

So how can web3 not being defined, if I get a connection with it?

Answer (score 1):

The web3 instance within your `if` statement comes from the `window` object. This occurs when MetaMask/Mist/Cipher injects it into the browser.

If you enter the `else` statement, this means that no web3 instance was found on the `window` object.  So, you manually create one from another provider (Infura, in your case).  Either way, web3 will be defined (in one way or another) after the `if...else` statements.

Once you have a defined instance of web3, you need to do something with it from within the `addEventListener()` function since it is asynchronous. Depending on how you are structuring you application, you could call a `startApp()` function (or another type of callback) which will have access to your defined web3 instance.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I have already tried `window.web3`. Getting the same error...

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the code that tries to use `web3` inside the `load` handler. As the code currently stands is, you're trying to use `web3` before you've defined it:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
        console.log('Web3 Detected! ' + web3.currentProvider.constructor.name)
        web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
    } else {
        console.log('No Web3 Detected... using HTTP Provider')
        web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://ropsten.infura.io/key"));
        if(!web3.isConnected())
            console.log("not connected");
        else
            console.log("connected"); 
    }
    web3.eth.defaultAccount = "0x...";
    var myContract = web3.eth.contract(...abi...);
    var myInstance = myContract.at('0x...');
});
```